# Simplifying a javascript with multiple functions to a single function array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, user-defined-functions

So I'm trying to simplify my script from having to use multiple functions with setintervals and clearintervals to have only one function that can be run simultaneously as if it were a bunch of different functions, like an array so the file is not so big. Here is an example of what the script does http://test.719records.com/test/test.html (Page is made to be viewed in 1080P or higher)
and here is the script as a whole 
http://test.719records.com/test/jquery.solari.letters.js

Here is an excerpt of the script that I want to end up being iterated.

```
//randomize name1 li:1 frames
//until correct character is landed on
var randlet = 0;

function randomizerlet1_1() {
    randlet = Math.floor(Math.random() * 156);
    timesletrun[0] += 1;
    if (masterlet[randlet] == letter[0]) {
        $('#flipL1_1').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
        clearInterval(intervallet1_1);
    } else {
        if (timesletrun[0] == 300) {
            masterlet[randlet] = letter[0];
            $('#flipL1_1').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
            clearInterval(intervallet1_1);
        } else {
            $('#flipL1_1').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
        }
    }
}

var intervallet1_1 = setInterval(function() {
    randomizerlet1_1();
}, 10);
```

and here would be the second letter in the sequence:

```
//randomize name1 li:2 frames
//until correct character is landed on
function randomizerlet1_2() {
    randlet = Math.floor(Math.random() * 156);
    timesletrun[1] += 1;
    if (masterlet[randlet] == letter[1]) {
        $('#flipL1_2').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
        clearInterval(intervallet1_2);
    } else {
        if (timesletrun[1] == 300) {
            masterlet[randlet] = letter[1];
            $('#flipL1_2').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
            clearInterval(intervallet1_2);
        } else {
            $('#flipL1_2').css('background-position', masterlet[randlet]);
        }
    }
}

var intervallet1_2 = setInterval(function() {
    randomizerlet1_2();
}, 10);
```

now there are 38 of these running in total for 1 line and there will end up being 28 lines. I'm sorry my knowledge is not at expert level, I'm still learning, so this might be easy and it might not be but I need to simplify these to one iterated function if its possible. Maybe using a multidimensional array and function arguments? I'm unsure how this code would look.

If this can be simplified I will be creating a tutorial for it and wrapping it into a free 3rd party plugin for people to use on their own personal projects!

Comment: Jättekul .... har vi blivit svenska ?

Comment: SEN NÄR!? BERÄTTA FÖR MIG!

Comment: This needs an OO approach. It is highly doable and should even create the page itself using a simple parameter of how many objects you want on the page. I wish I were better at OO since I would likely just code it with arrays for each thing that ends with x_y

Comment: Jag är inte svensk ... lol

Comment: Inte jag heller - Intervallet is Swedish - I see now it is interval let

Comment: @mplungjan ya me too, i've been messing with it for a few days now and can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: I think it's good to use Switch()...

Comment: @ReboKoye explain please?

Comment: I am still figuring it out

Comment: They both look similar except the index of letter[x] x=0, x=1.
and you want to combine both functions in 1 . am I right?

Comment: Jag är inte svensk, och inte sjuk heller, so I guess where back then? As your doing pretty much the same thing in all the conditionals, and in both functions, you could probably join it all together and use an object for the differences etc.

Comment: @ReboKoye yes that is correct, there will actually end up being a total of 38 inside of letter[x] for one line. not including the other lines.

Comment: @adeneo I'm not quite sure how that might be accomplished though, would you maybe have an example?

Comment: Here is the masterlet simplified http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bAD4Y/

Comment: @mplungjan wow, that is a very simple way to generate my array. I love it! Bonus points! lol

Comment: Actually reading the code, I do not think you actually use "flipx_y" at all but just an array: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m6byR/ and randlet = Math.floor(Math.random() * masterlet.length); BUT here you ruin it masterlet[randlet] = letter[0];

Comment: @mplungjan ya I fixed that in your script, cause i look for masterlet[randlet]

Comment: buddy of mine trying another approach http://test.719records.com/test2/test.html interesting outcome, really buggy though, progress to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start - work in progress

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m6byR/)

```
$(function() {
  var products= new Array(4);
  var letters = new Array(39);
  var numbers = new Array(4);
  $.each(products,function(i) {
    var aDIV = $("<div/>",{"class":"product"});
    var aUL  = $("<ul/>",{"class":"cd"});
    var logoLI = $("<li/>",{"class":"logo","id":"logo"+(i+1)});
    aUL.append(logoLI);
    var aLI;
    $.each(letters,function(j){
      aLI=$("<li/>",{"class":"flipletters","id":"flipL"+i+"_"+j,}).css("background-position", "0px 0px").appendTo(aUL);
    });
    $.each(numbers,function(j){
      aLI=$("<li/>",{"class":"flipdigits","id":"flip"+i+"_"+j,}).css("background-position", "0px 0px").appendTo(aUL);
    });
    $(".wrapper").append("<br style='clear:both'/>").append(aDIV.append(aUL));
  });
});
var masterlet = []
var cnt = 0;
$.each(",A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z".split(","),function(n, let) {
    for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
        masterlet.push("0px -"+(60*cnt++)+"px");
    }                
});
masterlet.push("0px -"+(60*cnt++)+"px");
masterlet.push("0px -"+(60*cnt++)+"px");




function randomizerlet(letId,letPos) {
    if (letPos) {
        this.letPos = letPos;
        this.timesletrun=0;
        this.letId = letId;
        this.tId=setInterval(function() {
          randomizerlet(letId);
        }, 10);
    }
    var randlet = masterlet[Math.floor(Math.random() * masterlet.length)];
    this.timesletrun++;
    var thisLI = $('#'+letId); 
    if (masterlet[randlet] == this.letPos) {
        thisLI.css('background-position', randlet);
        clearInterval(this.tId);
    } else {
        if (this.timesletrun == 300) {
            thisLI.css('background-position', this.letPos);
            clearInterval(this.tId);
        } else {
            thisLI.css('background-position', randlet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that does get rid of one line, not quite what I'm looking for though. I'd like to get rid of having to using 38 different functions just for one line let alone all 28 lines. 38x28= 1064 functions happening at the same time with setintervals = an unhappy browser :(

Comment: I'm doing a bit at a time. It is Easter and I have a family ;)

Comment: oh i'm in america and it is 100 and I probably will not be sleeping tonight as this is due tomorrow for me. lol

Comment: I'm sorry I'm such a noob, but I'm not quite following your example. would not timesletrun reset to 0 when it iterates through the function again? also i'm not quite sure what your passing with letPos.

Comment: I do not see you reset the timesletrun anywhere. I will get to the letPos in a minute

Comment: here it is or the first line: var timesletrun = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 38; x++) { timesletrun[x] = 0; }

Comment: That is not in the code I am looking at. Anyway when the function is called with a pos, it resets. I am not done. I cannot however work with a deadline of your new day. I am trying but no way

Comment: Where is Apo and comma 0,1,2,3 ?

Comment: http://test.719records.com/test/jquery.solari.letters.js It's right below the switch statement. oh it is fine, I posted this question to only see if someone might know easily how to simplify off the top of their head. I am still testing and changing things myself to make it work.

Comment: they are both left out of the array because i don't want it to flip through those 2 only to land on them. maybe later i will make flip images for them, but I have not yet.

Comment: It is a bit too much like work right now. I am on my Easter vacation. See the fiddle to get where I am. At least I cut down your masterlet and your hmtl

Comment: ja, definitely :) thank you. I think I will keep my html the way it is but I was gonna do something similar to what you did for when I wrap it up as a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: My fingers really itch to finish this. However I will not be near a real computer for quite a while...

Comment: here is what it looks like fully done across the page :) http://test.719records.com/test/index.html tv1 or tv2 links. A quick and dirty way for the jquery selector was also made up but not integrated yet     int masterletpos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i =< 6; i++)
    {
    for(int x = 0; x =< 43; x++)
    {String y = "#flipL"+ Integer.ToString(i) + "_" +     Integer.ToString(x);$(y).css('background-position',masterlet[pos[masterletpos]]);masterletpos++;}}   at the moment it is retrieving data from a json and a mysql table. now the fun part is I'm tryin to get it to read off of a POS system :(

Comment: I have one issue with the randomiser, I feel it does not look authentic. If you instead of using random, use the actual way such a sign works, it might look nicer and be simpler to code to boot. So each letter runs from space through A, B until the actual letter, and when the line needs to be refreshed, reset from space

Comment: yes, we had looked into this as well and had started on a script to do this but ran into problems that we could not figure out. located here: http://test.719records.com/test2/test.html. as you can see in the console window there is an error that we can't seem to get rid of and also it is very slow and high cpu intensive for some reason. But we are continuing to work on it as the possibility.

Comment: As I am on vacation I cannot help you since I only have an ipad without console